# How can I select datasource with dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, gridview

I have dropdownlist like this:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    Height="22px" Width="650px">
     <asp:ListItem> </asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>spy</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>uk</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>it</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And I use csv files for data. Like this:

```
spy.csv
uk.csv
it.csv
```

I can add 3 sqldatasources for 3 csv files and link gridview etc.

But I need to do, when I select spy on my dropdownlist, gridview use spydatasource, when I select uk, gridview use ukdatasource.

How can I do?

---

Datasources

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [spy.csv] WHERE ([Hostname] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Hostname" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [uk.csv] WHERE ([Hostname] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Hostname" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [it.csv] WHERE ([Hostname] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Hostname" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Please give some more code. How are you using the datasource currently?

Comment: There is no code, I'm using just standard sqldatasource. Added my first post.

Comment: How about changing the `SelectCommand` on your `SqlDataSource` in a callback function that you add to your `DropDownList`?

Comment: How can I do this? I try ([CSV] = ?) and added control parameter for this and link dropdownlist, but does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is going to be too much information to post into a comment, so I will write it in an answer. Please let me know if it is along the lines of what you are looking for.

Front-end:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    Height="22px" Width="650px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <asp:ListItem> </asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>spy</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>uk</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>it</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewID" .... >
 </asp:GridView>
```

Code-Behind

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)
  {
      var csvFile = DropDownList1.SelectedValue + ".csv";
      DataTable dt = //Convert csvFile to dataTable
      GridViewID.DataSource= dt;

      //This is an alternate method, setting the Select Command of a given SqlDataSource
      SqlDataSourceID.SelectCommand = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE ([Hostname] = ?)",csvFile);
  } 
}
```

Here is a short guide I found on how to convert CSV to GridView Datasource;
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hrojasara/how-you-can-use-csv-file-as-data-source-of-gridview/

EDIT:
Added an alternative way of handling changing DropDownList.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Didnt even know you could convert a csv to datatable, nice one

Comment: By using this method you don't have to have a bunch of datasources in your FrontEnd for no reason.

Comment: How can I change select command on Sqldatasource? I need like this actually: SELECT * FROM [$x.csv] and $x mean value on my dropdownlist.  Do I use like this?

Comment: If you use my method you don't actually need an `SqlDataSource`, but if you must use it I guess that you can set it. See my post edit.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

> protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>
> ```
>   if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "1ofthevalues")
>   {
>
>   yourGridview.DataSource= yourDataSourceID
>     yourGridview.DataBind();
>
>   } 
>
> }
> ```

Oh and add {OnSelectedIndexChanged= "DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"} to your dropdownlist

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1520: Method must have a return type
 DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

Comment: oh wait, change first line to : protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

Comment: There is no error after edited your post, but does not work on gridview. Return nothing.

Comment: also: add YourGridview.DataBind(); in the selectedindexchanged

Comment: Added databind but return white gridview. Datasources works fine by the way.

Comment: are you sure that it goes into the if? cause it should work.. maybe try removing the if for testing

Comment: Do I need put ; end of SqlDataSource1 ? Like this: GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1; but does not work. I try without if, does not work too.

Comment: yes you should ;), but you should use Sander's code, its better. And you can change the selectCommand with : SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "";

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Sander's comment.

Alternatively, I'd have three different data sources (each with different select commands). I'd have three connected to each correspondingly.

Based on my dropdown selection, I'd make the grid corresponding to the dropdown list's selected option visible.

This is a long shot for a small problem. But do-able simply via the designer only.